# Wrap single pattern occurring more than one time in a string using Regex and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
whatever [that's the pattern] by [pattern again] before [whatever].
```

I would love to wrap the brackets `[]` and everthing inside them in a span to be like:

```
whatever <span>[that's the pattern]</span> by </span>[pattern again]</span>
before <span>[whatever]</span>.
```

I have tried

```
re = new RegExp(/\[(.*)\]/);
var newString =  oldString.replace(re, "<span>$1</span>");
```

But this returns:

```
whatever <span>[that's the pattern] by [pattern again] before [whatever]</span>.
```

Before anyone shoot me about [why shouldn't I use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/497828), the reason I am doing this is because this string is echoed on the web page and the brackets and the text within has different color. I need to wrap them in a span to be able to style them. If there's a better solution I am open.

Many thanks!

Comment: `/.../` is already a `RegExp`; there is no point in calling the ctor

Comment: You need to HTML-escape your string to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from setting the global flag, you also need to make your regex lazy:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, "<span>[$1]</span>")
                                        ^    ^
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed. What do you mean by making regex lazy? If I understand well, this will make it stop to check if every character match?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy It will match the **minimum**, as opposed to the **maximum** (greedy). I'm not too sure about the exact matching process though, sorry ^^; You'll see that in your original regex, it matched everything till the last `]`, that's what's greedy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the global flag, which tells it to match more than once:

```
oldString.replace(/\[(.*)\]/g, ...)
```

Comment: Without global it will only match the first occurrence of the pattern